# Уменьшить нагрузку на запрос

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных сообщений со структурой:

```
id       - ID
user_id  - ID отправившего сообщение
owner_id - ID получившего сообщение
text     - текст сообщения
created  - дата создания в формате Y-m-d H:i:s
```

Данные в базе:

```
id | user_id | owner_id | text               | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |    1    |     2    | Привет Коля        | 2000-01-01 00:00:01
2  |    2    |     1    | Здорова Кирилл     | 2000-01-01 00:00:02
3  |    2    |     1    | Как дела?          | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
4  |    1    |     3    | Привет Серега!     | 2000-01-01 00:00:04
5  |    3    |     1    | ООО Кирюха привет! | 2000-01-01 00:00:05
6  |    2    |     3    | От Коли - Сергею   | 2000-01-01 00:00:06
7  |    3    |     1    | Есть денег в долг? | 2000-01-01 00:00:07
8  |    1    |     4    | Ну что у нас?      | 2000-01-01 00:00:08
```

Имеется следующий запрос:

```
'SELECT
    id, user_id, owner_id, text, created, (user_id + owner_id) uid
 FROM
    (SELECT *
     FROM messages
     ORDER BY created DESC) AS msg
 WHERE
    user_id = :user_id OR owner_id = :user_id
 GROUP BY uid
 ORDER BY created DESC
 LIMIT :limit'
```

При выборке хочу получить вот такой результат:

```
id | user_id | owner_id | uid | text               | created
-------------------------------------------------------------------
8  |    1    |     4    |  5  | Ну что у нас?      | 2000-01-01 00:00:08
7  |    3    |     1    |  4  | Есть денег в долг? | 2000-01-01 00:00:07
3  |    2    |     1    |  3  | Как дела?          | 2000-01-01 00:00:03
```

Как не выбирать под-запросом целую таблицу ? там же может быть до 1 000 000 записей!

Нужна группировка по максимальной дате

Comment: вы все испортили, создали вычисляемое не индексируемое поле, по которому группируете, добавили вложенный запрос, используете OR. Индексы у вас не используются никакие, отсюда и тормоза.  
Для таких запросов используют union, т.е. сначала выбирают записи для user_id потом для owner_id и делают union all из этих двух запросов.

Comment: Как сделать? Какой запрос необходимо сгенерировать?
Было бы вообще шикарно на ORM это все провернуть.
Сделано на Kohana 3

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
SELECT
   id, user_id, owner_id, text, created
FROM messages
WHERE
    user_id = 1
GROUP BY owner_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
   id, user_id, owner_id, text, created
FROM messages
WHERE
    owner_id = 1
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 10
```

При этом должны быть индексы по

- user_id
- owner_id

на больших объемах выборки будет эффективны составные индексы:

- user_id,created
- owner_id,created

ЗЫ для других субд, запрос будет сложнее, т.к. в группировку должны входить и другие поля (по которым нет агрегатной функции), а поля с бесконечной длиной типа text, входить в группу не могут, их придется обрезать, приводить к varchar(n)...

**UPD** [Фидл](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931fa/18)
Не очень красиво получается, конечно... Вместо id можно использовать как ключ created, если будет гарантия уникальности дат...

Comment: Каждый из запросов в UNION вернет не последние по дате данные. Надо бы добавить что-то типа HAVING BY created = max(created)

Comment: Не помогает такой запрос. Выводятся как 1 - 3 так и 3 - 1

1 - 3 это я написал пользователю с `ID 3`

3 - 1 это пользователь с `ID 3` ответил мне

Нужно получить последнее сообщение (либо ответ, либо мое сообщение адресату)

Может структуру БД саму поменять?

Comment: @BOPOH вернутся все записи, все верно, но группировка даст последние в соответствии с сортировкой.  

@Chetson, тогда без вложенного запроса не обойтись. Во вложенном запросе надо получить id тех записей, которые вам нужны. Надо думать, в окне ответа запрос писать сложно. Закиньте данные в http://sqlfiddle.com , поковыряем.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, оказывается логиниться не надо)) [ПРИМЕР](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f35/3)

Вернет 1,2,4, а надо 2,3,4. Т.е. надо 3,4, но все равно - "3" ваш вариант не вернет.

[ЭТО](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81f35/34/0) вернет уже то, что надо, но все равно долго. Быстрее, правда, чем у ТС, но все же...

@Chetson, а есть острая необходимость получать только последнюю запись из отправленных мною/мне?

Если да - можно предложить следующий вариант - заводите дополнительную табличку последних сообщений. Добавили запись - обновили последнее сообщение у себя и у получателя.

Comment: @BOPOH, вы правы, mysql любит выбирать при группировке данные из разных кортежей. (на sqlfiddle не надо логиниться)

@Chetson, обновил ответ